# Login button not disappearing after login

Tags: php, facebook, button, facebook-login

I have just began to learn php and I'm working on a Facebook app at the moment. The problem I am facing now is that the login button remains on the screen even after the user has accessed his account. Does anyone have an explination for this?
Here is my code:

```
<?php if (isset($user_profile)) {
  ?>
         user logged in
<?php }  else { ?>

  <div class="fb-login-button" data-scope="email"></div>

<?php } ?>
```

I included a file where $user_profile is defined as $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');

Comment: I think your `$user_profile` variable is not set, huh? Please show us where you set the variable.

Comment: @sebastian I have a file named `utils.php` and I set `$user_profile` there. I used `require_once` to make it recognise the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Test the output of $user_profile using the var_dump( $user_profile ) command. You could also add the exit command after var_dump to pause execution. From your code sample the else block is being run meaning there is an issue with your $user_profile variable.

Comment: No, it means that if the user is not logged in, the login button should appear. However the problem is that after the login, it does not disappear

Comment: Have you tried echoing the else block in php fashion such as 
echo '<div class="fb-login-button" data-scope="email"></div>' or an elseif block using } elseif(!isset($user_profile)) { ...

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled php error logging? what does the log says?

It rather difficult to help you debug without seeing your utils.php

isset is a function that returns true if a variable is created and has a value.

By your accounts, that means your $facebook->api('/me') is returning a null or that line of code didn't run at all.

Can't know for sure what went wrong with your codes because without seeing what you're doing, I'm only guessing.

Anyway, since you're using PHP, how about omitting the need for a login button in the first place? just prompt for user login as soon as they enter the app (if they've not logged into Facebook), if a Facebook session is received, show them the actual app and you'll already have the user profile info to play with. How's that sound?

Here's what I usually do in my Facebook apps. You can tweak it any way you like to suit your needs.

**config.php**

```
<?php
//set facebook application id, secret key and api key here
    $fbconfig['appid'] = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    $fbconfig['secret'] = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    $protocol = "http";

    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']))
    {
        if($_SERVER['HTTPS'])
        {
            $protocol = "https";
        }
    }
//set application urls here
    $domainName = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

    $appNamespace = "[APP_NAMESPACE]";
    $appFolder = "[WEB_FOLDER_NAME]";

    $fbconfig['appBaseUrl'] =   $protocol."://apps.facebook.com/".$appNamespace;
    $fbconfig['baseUrl']    =   $protocol."://" . $domainName . "/" . $appFolder;

    $uid = null; // facebook user id
    $me = null; // JSON object containing the basic user information

    $redirect_url = $fbconfig['baseUrl']."/redirect.php";
    $cancel_url = $protocol."://www.facebook.com";
    $allow_url = $fbconfig['appBaseUrl'];

    $profileURL = $protocol."://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=";
?>
```

**redirect.php**

```
<?php
include_once "config.php";
if (isset($_REQUEST["error"]))
{
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        top.location.href = "<?=$cancel_url?>";
    </script>
    <?php
}
else
{
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        top.location.href = "<?=$allow_url?>";
    </script>
    <?php

}


?>
```

**fbmain.php**

```
<?php
include_once "../facebook_sdk/facebook.php";
include_once "config.php";


    $uid = null; // facebook user id
    $me = null; // JSON object containing the basic user information

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $fbconfig['appid'],
  'secret' => $fbconfig['secret'],
  'cookie' => true,
));

$signedRequest = $facebook->getSignedRequest();

// We may or may not have this data based on a $_GET or $_COOKIE based session.
//
// If we get a session here, it means we found a correctly signed session using
// the Application Secret only Facebook and the Application know. We dont know
// if it is still valid until we make an API call using the session. A session
// can become invalid if it has already expired (should not be getting the
// session back in this case) or if the user logged out of Facebook.
$user = $facebook->getUser();
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
                array(
                    //state what are the required perms
                    'redirect_uri' => $redirect_url,
                    'scope' => 'email, user_likes, user_status, friends_likes, friends_status',
                )
            );

// Session based API call.
if ($user) {
  try {
    $me = $facebook->api('/me');
    if($me)
    {
        $uid = $me['id']; 
        $_SESSION['fbId'] = $me['id'];
    }
  } 
  catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);   
  }
}
else {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
    exit;
}

function outputData($d){
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($d);
    echo '</pre>';
}
?>
```

after that I just need to include "fbmain.php" in any page that requires a facebook session. I'll usually put the include in my "index.php".

**index.php**

```
<?php
include_once "fbmain.php";
?>

<html>
    <body id="my_body">
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId: '<?php echo $facebook->getAppID() ?>',
          cookie: true,
          xfbml: true,
          oauth: true
        });

        FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
        FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0,0);
      };

      (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
          '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      }());
    </script>

    <?php
        if ($me)
        {
            echo "Facebook ID: ".$me['id']. "<br />"; 
            echo "Facebook Name: ".$me['name'];
        }
    ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

subsequent pages in the site will use the session variables to make api calls using the Javascript SDK instead of going through the whole authentication flow again.

Comment: it does not return null. After login there appears both user is logged in and the login button. I reload after login with window.location=window.location, because the app might be used in a frame